View split on left / right makes chrome bleed over vertically
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
Maximizing Chrome works fine, but when I send Chrome to left / right of my monitor, it bleeds over the monitor real state, vertically: the lower couple of lines are not visible.
This only happens when disabling "Use system title bars and borders" in Chrome - which I need because it offers a bigger window.
This is exclusively a Chrome problem - other applications are working fine - connected to the way Chrome computes its size when not using the system chrome.
I am running the latest Chrome version: Version 126.0.6478.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
This question is related to this one, but that one is quite old and marked as solved. It seems the problem has appeared again?
Is there any known solution?
